# How to define a std::function for a generic function?

Tags: c++, templates, functional-programming

How to define a std::function for a generic or template function? For example, we can do

```
std::function<bool(int a)> f = [](int a){return a < 0;};
```

How to generalize it for other argument types of a like the following

```
std::function<bool(auto a)> f = [](auto a){return a < 0;};
```

Comment: Is it strictly necessary to use a `std::function` rather than just `auto` to store the lambda?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Create a comparison to zero for each type supporting the `<` operator?

Comment: Besides, you syntax is wrong. It should be `std::function<bool(int)> lessThanZero = [](int a){return a < 0;};`

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Yes, you are right.

Comment: Is your comment referred to the syntactical remark or the previous "what are you trying to achieve"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  Such a construct would require something akin to an entire C++ compiler be type erased by `std::function`, which seems overkill for most applications.

Odds are your problem does not actually require something that strong.

If ypu have a fixed set of argument types, there are solutions aplenty.  For every type?  Nope.